# set ImageView above Textview

Tags: imageview, android-imageview, textview, android

I just want to do a very simple think :

I want to put an ImageView on full screen with just a simple TextView on his Bottom, not Over but just on his bottom..

I tried some combination but nothing worked fine..

Here is my current basic XML code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgset"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:src="@drawable/creditview" />

    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutimgset"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This spot is for Ad"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:background="@color/white" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This only show the ImageView..

Answer (score 0):

Try to use for your ImageView this:

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

In this case you don't need RelativeLayout.
Or put all to RelativeLayout and use

```
android:layout_below="@+id/imgset"
```

for your TextView